IIS Worker Processes - Translating Requests - Odd Querystrings
In trying to track down some slow page load times, I've begun to look at the IIS Worker Processes.
I am new to interpreting the IIS Worker Processes (Requests) section, and I've noticed that a repeated pattern occurs.
The web.config rewrite rule is:
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{URL}" pattern="^(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?p={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>

Here is an example of the listings in the Worker Processes.  They occur in pairs, showing the URL rewrite process and the FastCGI process.
The listings are always in pairs like this, with the encoded characters in the querystring, and sometimes repeated parameters.  Here, the encoded character is %3F for question mark, which is odd, given that it should be the ampersand.  The repetition of the parameters is random, and on some requests for this page, there is no repetition.  This page actually does function, so I'm at a loss to understand why these processes are appearing in the queue and with the odd querystrings:
/directory/sam-smith?profile_page=1%3Fdetail_page=1%3detail_page=7%3Fdetail_page=7%3Fdetail_page=7%3F
BeginRequest - RewriteModule
/index.php?p=directory/sam-smith&profile_page=1%3Fdetail_page=1%3detail_page=7%3Fdetail_page=7%3Fdetail_page=7%3F
ExecuteRequestHandler - FastCgiModule

Would the repetition of some parameters and not others be a URL Rewrite Module problem?  Would the appearance of encoded characters be a normal thing here (although the question mark instead of ampersand is odd)?  Thanks for any leads!

You can use failed request tracking to trace the full rewrite and FastCGI process for any abnormalities, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Thank you.  In viewing Failed Request Tracing, I am not seeing the same requests in the Worker Processes, although I have refreshed the list there, and revisited the FREB log files.  There is no error referenced in the log, so I have been querying FREB based upon time (currently 2 seconds).  Would it be better to query another way?

You might also try to look into the IIS logs (C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles) to correlate with the Worker Processes. The IIS logs can give you detailed information about incoming requests, including full query strings and response times, which you can match with the Worker Processes to see if the slow requests are logged there.
